# How to remap Back and Forward key on a Lenovo ThinkPad T420?

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, thinkpad, remapping

I used to have a Lenovo N500, in this laptop the *PgUp and PgDn keys are next to the Up/Down/Left/Right keys*.
Now I have a Lenovo T420 and the keys next to Up/Down/Left/Right are **Back** and **Forward**.

I would like to know how to remap the Back and Forward keys to function as PgUp and PgDn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be made just typing the following command

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 166=Prior' && xmodmap -e 'keycode 167=Next'
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative version of @miguelmorales85's answer (may be a bit more robust):

```
xmodmap -e 'keysym XF86Back = Prior' -e 'keysym XF86Forward = Next'
```

Comment: This answer worked for me in Xfce + Compiz, the other one didn't!